# Where can I find the source code for Redhat's nash utility?

Tags: redhat, boot, initrd

Where can I find the source code for Redhat's nash utility?

Thanks,
Chenz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

git://git.fedoraproject.org/git/hosted/mkinitrd

Comment: It's now moved to here: git://pkgs.fedoraproject.org/mkinitrd

Answer (score 0):

The source is located in the mkinitrd package.